# File not unstash in slave machine of jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I used the ubundu as a master machine of jenkins server and configured windows machine as the slave. I tried to stash and unstash a file from master to slave's worksapce but it is not unstashed.

```
node('slave') {
   node('master'){
     stash includes: "file.tgz" name: "master-stash"
   }
   unstash "master-stash"
   bat "ls"
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stash
Stashed 1 file(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] unstash
```

The file can be stashed from the master, but it is not unstashed in the slave's workspace.

jenkins: 2.35

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use:

`unstash name: 'stash_name'`

I'm using Jenkins at 2.47 version and it works for me. One thing here is that, if you include "rootFolder/file.tgz", your unstash will gives you the entire path with the file. If you want to get just the file and put it on the current directory, you should use:

`dir('path to file'){
    stash name: 'my_stash' includes:'file.something'
}
unstash name:'my_stash'
sh 'ls'`

The output of `sh'ls .'` will shows you "file.something" and the other files from the folder that you makes unstash.

Comment: Using `dir` to change directory of the file I want to `stash` solved the problem for me

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the stash ans unstash problem by adding root folder in the stash includes. I don't know why it is not unstash a single file, but it can unstash a root folder with file.

```
node('slave') {
   node('master'){
     stash includes: "rootFolder/file.tgz" name: "master-stash"
   }
   unstash "master-stash"
   bat "ls"
}
```

The unstash file can be get from rootFolder/file.tgz of current workspace.

Comment: I'm expiriencing simmilar. What is "rootFolder" in this case? And why it should work if file was as well stashed before?